# App size on Google Play Console different with Google Playstore

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have app build with flutter and build release the aab, then i publish it to Google Playstore. When i see app release in [Google Play Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcQfU.png) , app size is **9.62 MB** but when i see my my app on playstore on real device app size is **19 MB**.

 What i want ask , is this really the way it works? Already clear cache Google Playstore on my device but have same result.

[image]

Comment: I guess the app is not rolled out for you when you tried. Give it some time

Comment: Production track? If so, that could be a bug: reach out to Play developer support.

Comment: It's already solved after i release update version to my app.

Answer (score -2):

What your looking at on the play console is the app's download size. This will be the app in a compressed form to be more efficient for downloads. When the app is downloaded it will then be decompressed and is resulting in the size difference your observing.

You will notice that there is a second tab on your Play Store console(it's visible in your screenshot) that is "App size on device (at install time)". If you look under this tab you should see a size that more accurately reflects what is on your device.

Comment: Yes , i know when App is installed will be large than before compressed. But my understanding , tab "App Download Size" is describe what user see on Google Playstore when in this tab 9 MB then it should be 9 MB too on Playstore. I said it because my another publish app size same with google play console and google playstore

Comment: I believe that Google Play displays sizes in the uncompressed value so users don't get surprised when a app is larger when installed vs downloaded.